# Resolving “Could not connect to the reCAPTCHA service. Please check your internet connection and reload to get a reCAPTCHA challenge.”

Tags: recaptcha

Im using up to date chrome but when i try to do recaptcha i get error, but when i go to other browser such as Brave works fine... Does anyone have same problem? (Went thru all posts about this problem but no help)
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlpOd.png)